# Regex to enforce password requirements

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I'm trying to write regex to validate the password for the given rule.

Passwords must be at least 8 characters in length and **contain at least 3 of the following 4 types of characters:**

- lower case letters (i.e. a-z)
- upper case letters (i.e. A-Z)
- numbers (i.e. 0-9)
- special characters (e.g. !@#$&*)

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength) discussion and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength#answer-5142164) really great answer over there.

Now I'm trying to write regex for the mentioned requirements and I came up with the solution like this

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$
```

and it is working perfect see [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/Drwq39CvTi) but I want to optimize these regex and I'm not sure If there are any way to simplify this.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697815/regex-for-combination-of-given-rules)

Comment: If possible, drop those silly rules and use a password strength estimator, like [zxcvbn](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/) instead. Your rules prevent many strong passwords (e.g. 32 random hex characters which have 128 bits of entropy)  and allow super weak passwords like `Password1`

Comment: On a usability note, **don’t** use such simplistic password quality filters, they are crap, infuriatingly annoying for users, and indeed peddle a false understanding of IT security: Passwords can be completely safe and still violate your rules (and, conversely, a passing password may still be unsafe).

Comment: Every time I have to enter a password and space and punctuation is not accepted, I die a little inside. I should be allowed to write a sentence in there, if I want to. There is no sensible reason to disallow it - the password is going to just be hashed and salted anyway, _right_? Why does it matter what goes in - it's not like you have limitations on the data that goes into the field - the hashed value would be garbled but of valid type - whether your database handles, say, commas or umlauts or spaces is irrelevant.

Comment: You tagged this question as both [tag:ruby] and [tag:javascript]. Since regex dialects differ by language, please clarify how you intend to use this regex, preferably by including the Ruby and/or JavaScript code.

Comment: Take those pesky rules out and shoot them!  Passphrases are so much better and yet won't pass.

Comment: Give the guy a break. He's likely just doing what the official security policy in his company tells him to do, no need to berate him for that. There are quite a few other glaring problems that could be pointed out helpfully (like, `if it does what it needs to do, why optimize at all?` or `how do you know it does what you want (it doesn't - regexpes can't do what he's asking)`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Split the regex into smaller parts to check each rule individually.

Here's the code for JavaScript. The same *simple* logic can be used for Ruby or any other language.

```
// Check the length
if (str.length >= 8 && validate()) {

}

// Check if all the characters are present in string
function validate(string) {
    // Initialize counter to zero
    var counter = 0;

    // On each test that is passed, increment the counter
    if (/[a-z]/.test(string)) {
        // If string contain at least one lowercase alphabet character
        counter++;
    }
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(string)) {
        counter++;
    }
    if (/[0-9]/.test(string)) {
        counter++;
    }
    if (/[!@#$&*]/.test(string)) {
        counter++;
    }

    // Check if at least three rules are satisfied
    return counter >= 3;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[@Tushar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/79668/tushar)'s idea isn't bad, but it is **NOT** optimal for re-usability and extensability.

What I propose is to filter out the rules that failed. This way, you can count how many failed a bit faster, instead of having a counter.
Even if it isn't that much faster, it is still easier to add rules.

```js
function validate(string) {
    if(string.length < 8)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var rules = [
        /[a-z]/, //letters (lower-case)
        /[A-Z]/, //letters (upper-case)
        /\d/, //numbers (similar to /[0-9]/)
        /[!@#$&*]/ //some symbols
    ];

    return rules.filter(function(rule){
        return rule.test(string);
    }).length >= 3;
}
```

Yes, there is a magic number. I don't see any other way to improve it. If you want, you can do the oposite and count how many rules *failed*.
This may be a bit more flexible, if you want to allow some rules to fail.

---

Speed-wise, it is up to 5 times slower, but sometimes it is faster.
I guess is has something to do with the `.filter` method.

Here's how I tested the speed:

```js
function validate_mine(string) {
    if(string.length < 8)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var rules = [
        /[a-z]/, //letters (lower-case)
        /[A-Z]/, //letters (upper-case)
        /\d/, //numbers (similar to /[0-9]/)
        /[!@#$&*]/ //some symbols
    ];

    return rules.filter(function(rule){
        return rule.test(string);
    }).length >= 3;
}

function validate_Tusha(string) {
    // Initialize counter to zero
    var counter = 0;

    // On each test that is passed, increment the counter
    if (/[a-z]/.test(string)) {
        // If string contain at least one lowercase alphabet character
        counter++;
    }
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(string)) {
        counter++;
    }
    if (/[0-9]/.test(string)) {
        counter++;
    }
    if (/[!@#$&*]/.test(string)) {
        counter++;
    }

    // Check if at least three rules are satisfied
    return counter >= 3;
}

console.time('validate_mine');
[
 'test it',
 'Me want this!',
 'Th1s_is_cool',
 '$tuff!_should-be-fast',
 'now! run it!'
].map(validate_mine);
console.timeEnd('validate_mine');

console.time('validate_Tusha');
[
 'test it',
 'Me want this!',
 'Th1s_is_cool',
 '$tuff!_should-be-fast',
 'now! run it!'
].map(validate_Tusha);
console.timeEnd('validate_Tusha');
```

---

If you want to make something extremelly extensible, one could follow [@Vld](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/110993/vld)'s idea and pass a list of rules to a function, and an optional parameter to relax how many rules can be missed.

Something similar to this:

```js
function validate(string, rules, min_pass) {
    'use strict';
    if(min_pass < 0 || min_pass > rules.length)
    {
        throw new RangeError('min_pass should be between 0 and ' + rules.length);
    }

    return rules.filter(function(rule){
        if(rule instanceof Function)
        {
            return !!rule.bind(string)(string);
        }
        else if(rule instanceof RegExp)
        {
            return rule.test(string);
        }
        return false;
    }).length >= min_pass;
}
```

This accepts 3 parameters:

- `string`: The string to be tested,
- `rules`: An array of regular expressions or functions,
- `min_pass`: Minimum number of rules to pass.

To obtain the results you want, using this new method, you could do like this:

```
validate(
    'string here',
    [
        /[a-b]/,
        /[A-B]/,
        /\d/,
        /[!@#$&*]/
    ],
    3
);
```

You still have to validate the length before, since I don't have a way to say that a rule is important or something.
The formatting still isn't optimal, but you get the idea.

---

Also, this is not a good way to check security. With your rules, a password like `Passw0rd!` is valid, but we all know how crappy that is. Any password cracker worth it's salt will have rules to try these permutations. Heck, it may even be the one of the very first words in the dictionary list!
This will leave you prone to dictionary-based attacks.
Just make sure you use a good and unique salt, with a strong hash (like SHA256) instead of relying on this type of rules to check password strength.
This fails for passwords like `ñó wÿn fõr ýôü`, which may be far more secure than some of the passwords you validate.

Comment: But the problem is that you need to have at least 3 out of 4. Doesn't that solution require _all_ rules to match? Also, you aren't showing separate uppercase and lowercase rules, whereas they need to be distinct.

Comment: @Vld You mean, the first rule? It matches *both* upper and/or lower.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem. `password123` and `Password123` are different - the latter should be valid according to OP's requirements. With your validation it won't be. `Password_` should also be valid. While `Password_123` and `password_123`  would be valid with yours, it's incidental, not explicitly checking for the requirements.

Comment: @Vld Give me 2 minutes

Comment: @Vld What do you think now? I hope it is better now.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I didn't think of doing that way. Performance-wise it should be the same as @Tushar's answer, I think but I'm not really sure there is a way around this, since you have to find at `x` out of `y` things, hence you need to evaluate (potentially) everything. I guess a `reduce` could just stop when enough rules are hit. Then again, the number of times this will be executed mean any optimisation is wasted - it's not going to be run constantly but only on login/registration

Comment: @Vld I saw the duplicated rule and updated it 2 minutes ago. I think there will be some overhead to the `.filter` method, but it shouldn't be that much. At least, I can say that this method is cleaner and easier to update/upgrade/extend than Tusha's solution. I think that's the only point going for this answer.

Comment: I also agree it's cleaner. There is a benefit for being shorter and simpler. For enhance reusability (if you want to validate different passwords?) the function signature could be changed to `validate(rules, minPassing, value)`. With that, partial application could be used to define the validation as long as the same framework is preserved. The actual validation can be a partially applied function like so `pw_validate = validate.bind(null, [ /[a-z]/, /[A-Z]/, /\d/, /[!@#$&*]/ ], 3)`. `minLength` can also be extracted, if needed. Not sure if that'd be useful but it's more modular.

Comment: @Vld I had that in mind while coming home. To actually have that set of parameters on that way. I have an idea and will post it in a bit

Comment: @Vld I hope you had this in mind. I've added what I though you meant, and that I though on my way back.

Comment: Not exactly. If you change `string` to be the last parameter, then you can use [partial application](http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/) to create a new function. I'll repost my previous example `pw_validate = validate.bind(null, [ /[a-z]/, /[A-Z]/, /\d/, /[!@#$&*]/ ], 3)` - this "locks in" the first two parameters and thus you have a new effective function `pw_validate(string)`. Advantage is that the caller doesn't need to pass the correct parameters and you can call the same validation without synchronising the calls.

Comment: I was thinking of [something like this](https://jsbin.com/zogedaqani/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Vld That isn't that much different. Except yours has the length validation inside, while mine requires it to be outside. Also, yours only takes regular expressions, while mine also takes functions. But yours looks a little better. Do you want me to include it in the answer?

Comment: Feel free. It could be modified to take functions, of course, I just kept it to be the same initial idea - list of regexes. In reality, you are most likely better to pass an object with configuration, like `{rules: [], min_length: 8, min_valid_rules: 1}` instead of a list of parameters but it's there to illustrate the idea. Regarding functions - instead of `func.bind(string)(string)`, it's probably easier to use `.apply()`

Comment: @Vld If it is to do as you said, it's better to use a jQuery plugin, like https://jqueryvalidation.org/ . And the reason why I use `func.bind(string)(string)` is to allow things like `_ => _.length > 7` (ES6 style) or like `function(string){ return string.length > 7; }` (ES5 style). It is **VERY** ugly, but very useful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, I think regex is the wrong approach here. Just go with regular form validation code - take the value, validate its length, set a counter to 0, and then for each requirement that it meets, increment the counter. Then check if it meets at least 3 by checking the counter.

The resulting code will be understandable for any programmer that comes across the code. It will be possible to easily change the rules to allow other special characters, to disallow certain common passwords, to change the length...

Your long regex is, whilst properly formatted, a real pain to maintain. You can still use the individual sub-expressions in your validation code, but it'll be a lot more readable.

Answer (score 1):

No.

<s>This is not a regular grammar.</s> Regular expressions are not the right tool for this job.

Check string length and for the existence of character code points within each of the necessary ranges.

Better still, follow the other suggestions to push for a more legitimate password complexity algorithm.

*I'll let someone edit in the appropriate and obligatory xkcd and stock overflow references.*

Comment: It's a regular grammar, though the theoretical regular expression is rather complex. Anyway, it's true that regular expression is too clunky for this use case.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'll take your word for it. Procedural validation is straight forward enough I can't force my brain to try a regex approach.

Comment: It's a _very_ regular grammar. If you think about it in a straightforward way - you could create a RegExp that does `|` between all the different orders of 3 of the 4 requirements (with anything in between and after) and if one of those matches the regexp matches. Writing a regexp is easy but it's clearly not a good idea. A good way to think about non-regular grammars is that they require some sort of "memory" or the ability to "keep track" of an unbounded amount of things. For any bounded amount (3 in this case) the grammar is regular.